# Documenting illegible documents

Tags: mysql, perl, substring

I'm trying to make a searchable record of hand-written documents. Some of them are very unclear at times and I'm looking for the most efficient way to capture them in a database but still be able to search for terms utilising any of the possible branches of letters/words.

My current idea is below...but I think a query looking for "Tom Sawyer" would be very slow to achieve like this. Does anyone know how best to go about this?

```
Table: FullTexts
FullTextID  FullText
0001        This text was written by T{*1}m {*2}
0002        This document was even more {*1} to read

Table: Changes
DocID  ChangeID  ChangeIter  ChangeText
00001  1         1           i
00001  1         1           o
00001  1         2           Sawyer
00001  1         2           Sayor
00002  1         1           fun
00002  1         1           hard
00002  1         1           messy
```

...or perhaps only a modified FullTexts table with all variations concatenated between {} and then scanned using Perl expressions in the WHERE clause?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`DBIx::NoSQL`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::NoSQL) may be worth a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql and regex are suboptimal tools for this kind of search.

You generate the variants as you mentioned in the question and parse all text into n-grams. Then you feed them into a search engine that uses n-grams as input, not raw text.

Comment: Thanks very much Daxim - I'd heard of N-grams before but never crossed my mind for this...I'll do some reading! :)